# invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'QStaticAssertFailure<false>' at QGlobal.h

Tags: c++, qt, sizeof

I am currently migrating a huge project from Qt 4.x to 5.2.1, Everything has been rather good until this error, which I find incredibly confusing because its located at the Qt files, and I believe the solution must be applied somewhere else, not in the qglobal.h located at 5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qglobal.h.
The error must be happening somewhere else.

Heres the error:

> ..........\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/**qglobal.h**:681:85: error: **invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'QStaticAssertFailure'**
>        enum {Q_STATIC_ASSERT_PRIVATE_JOIN(q_static_assert_result, **COUNTER**) = sizeof(QStaticAssertFailure)}
>                                                                                        ^
>
> ..........\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qglobal.h:686:47:
>   note: in expansion of macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT'  #define
>   Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) Q_STATIC_ASSERT(Condition)
>                                                  ^
>
> ..........\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qobject.h:520:5:
>   note: in expansion of macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
>        Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QtPrivate::HasQ_OBJECT_Macro::Value,
>        ^

Here's the piece of code in qglobal.h

```
// Intentionally undefined
template <bool Test> class QStaticAssertFailure;
template <> class QStaticAssertFailure<true> {};

#define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_PRIVATE_JOIN(A, B) Q_STATIC_ASSERT_PRIVATE_JOIN_IMPL(A, B)
#define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_PRIVATE_JOIN_IMPL(A, B) A ## B
#ifdef __COUNTER__
#define Q_STATIC_ASSERT(Condition) \
    enum {Q_STATIC_ASSERT_PRIVATE_JOIN(q_static_assert_result, __COUNTER__) = sizeof(QStaticAssertFailure<!!(Condition)>)}
#else
#define Q_STATIC_ASSERT(Condition) \
    enum {Q_STATIC_ASSERT_PRIVATE_JOIN(q_static_assert_result, __LINE__) = sizeof(QStaticAssertFailure<!!(Condition)>)}
#endif /* __COUNTER__ */
#define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) Q_STATIC_ASSERT(Condition)
#endif
```

I have tried everything and have researched all about it, but didnt find a proper solution. I have wasted all day in this annoying piece of code. I hope someone can shed some light on the matter.

Thankyou very much.

EDIT: I searched for all the documents that included qglobal.h, but none of them make use of any assert funcion, so I dont know what could be triggering such error. Theres no way that the qglobal.h is wrong, so it must be something of the source code.

EDIT2: I managed to isolate the lines that trigger the error, apparently the compilation output gave more information than I thought, but it was so 'separated' that I thought it was a warning and had nothing to do. Here is the code from my application. The two commented lines are the ones that trigger the error. Sorry for my mistake.

```
bool ISPSModel::removeGraphics(GraphicsPrimitive* _gtr) {

    for (int _i = 0; _i < ispss.size(); _i++) {

        for (int _j = 0; _j < ispss[_i]->graphicsObjects.size(); _j++) {

            if (ispss[_i]->graphicsObjects[_j] != _gtr)
                continue;

            if (ispss[_i]->graphicsObjects.contains(_gtr)) {

                //beginRemoveRows(indexFromItem(ispss[_i]->m_item), _gtr->getData(DATA_ROLE).value<ISPSItem*>()->row(), _gtr->getData(DATA_ROLE).value<ISPSItem*>()->row());
               //_gtr->getData(DATA_ROLE).value<ISPSItem*>()->remove();
                ispss[_i]->removeGraphics(ispss[_i]->graphicsObjects[_j]);
                endRemoveRows();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Its this part the one that causes the error:

```
value<ISPSItem*>()
```

Heres the other part of the compilation error that I had ignored, in case it can help:

> ..........\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qobject.h: In
>   instantiation of 'T qobject_cast(QObject*) [with T = ISPSItem*]':
>   ..........\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qvariant.h:695:51: 
>   required from 'static T
>   QtPrivate::QVariantValueHelper::object(const QVariant&) [with T =
>   ISPSItem*]'
>   ..........\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qvariant.h:101:37: 
>   required from 'static ReturnType QtPrivate::ObjectInvoker::invoke(Argument) [with Derived =
>   QtPrivate::QVariantValueHelper; Argument = const QVariant&;
>   ReturnType = ISPSItem*]'
>   ..........\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qvariant.h:810:64: 
>   required from 'T qvariant_cast(const QVariant&) [with T = ISPSItem*]'
>   ..........\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qvariant.h:348:36: 
>   required from 'T QVariant::value() const [with T = ISPSItem*]'
>   ..\marssies\**ispswidget.cpp:785:109:   required from here**
>   EDIT3:
>   I left those 2 lines commented and kept migrating the application, until I got the same error in another file, this is the line:

Im getting the same error in another .cpp using a different class, but what they have in common is the `.value<Type>();`

```
Notify* _n = ui.notifyBox->model()->data(index, Qt::UserRole).value<Notify*>();
```

So definitely its the `.value<Type>();` what throws the error, now the only thing left is to find a way around it.

Here is the object ISPSItem in case its useful:

```
class ISPSItem : public QObject {

public:
    enum Level {ROOT_LEVEL = 1,
                    ISPS_LEVEL,
                        GRAPHICS_LEVEL
                    } level;

    ISPSItem(ISPSItem* = NULL, Level = ROOT_LEVEL, int = -1);
    ~ISPSItem();

    ISPSItem* parentItem() {return _parentItem;}

    ISPSItem* child(int);
    void appendChild(ISPSItem*);
    void insertChild(ISPSItem*, int);
    int childCount() const {return children.size();}

    int row() const;
    int newNodeRow(Level);
    void remove();

private:
    QList<ISPSItem*> children;
    ISPSItem* _parentItem;
    void remove(ISPSItem*);
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ISPSItem*)
```

Comment: This is Qt code, but what is **your** code that produces this error?

Comment: Thats the thing, I have no idea which part of the code triggers this, and the compilator doesnt offer any info. Id try to find it but I didnt program it and there are 798 .cpps and .h's, its driving me crazy
EDIT: I found all the files that include qglobal.h, but none of them use any kind of assert function.

Comment: @vahancho Such an error ist not always traceble to your own code. Something includes something which includes something which includes `qglobal.h`. I have a similar problem which fortunately only results in a warning so i can ignore it but it also resides in `qglobal.h` and occured when i ported to `Qt 5.2.1`

Comment: Just out of curiosity....can you trace this down to a specific file being compiled and maybe `undef __COUNTER__` on the top to see what happens? Maybe this define is new to `5.2.1` but also used for something completly different by something else in your or 3rd party code.

Comment: As vahancho wrote, please show more information about your code. For instance, show the _whole_ compiler error output which gives some starting from _your_ code.

Comment: @vahancho I managed to isolate the error, it was a completely stupid mistake for my part, check the edit if you have the time please :) thankyou

Comment: @VíctorAsdasd, good. And what is `ISPSItem`?

Comment: @vahancho its a class, I will edit my post with it now, but Im not sure if its relevant, because I get the same error on another .cpp, using a different class inside the <>. Thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After getting much information about the error and the sources that trigger it I conclude, that the root cause could be in using `QObject` subclasses in QVariant, especially when calling `QVariant::value()` function. As Qt docs say:

> If the QVariant contains a pointer to a type derived from QObject then
>   T may be any QObject type. If the pointer stored in the QVariant can
>   be qobject_cast to T, then that result is returned. Otherwise a null
>   pointer is returned. **Note that this only works for QObject subclasses
>   which use the Q_OBJECT macro**.

I believe, that adding `Q_OBJECT` macro to these classes (`ISPSItem`) declaration will solve the problem.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I am using QtCreator 3.3.2 on Qt 5.4.1. When I added `Q_OBJECT` to the header file, the errors greatly changed. I did a `Build / Clean All`. But the error remained. Only after deleting the build directory, which still had the `makefile` in it, and a fresh build all, it compiled without error. Just to be sure, I removed the `Q_OBJECT` and built, which made the errors return and then replacing it made the errors change again as before. Then only deleting the build directory allowed a clean build. Same thing twice. Definitely needed both.

Comment: @Harvey, after you added `Q_OBJECT` you need to run Qt's `qmake` tool to generate/update the appropriate moc files. Only after that you need to compile your project.

Answer (score 3):

Add this before you use ISPSItem as a QVariant cast:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ISPSItem)
```

To solve the problem you need to add your class to QMetaType, the macro do that.

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Type)
```

This macro makes the type Type known to QMetaType as long as it provides a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor. It is needed to use the type Type as a custom type in QVariant.

Good look!

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, although Its been a long time since I had to deal with this. Hope it helps other people!

Answer (score 2):

I see this problem when I change signals variable type but at the same time I forgot changing slots descriptions.For example;
I have a signal slot :  this is signal-> setResult(bool res);
                        this is slot  -> setResult(bool res){}

I change signal's type  signal -> setResult(QString res);
                        slot   -> setResult(**bool res**);  /////***WHEN I FORGOT CHANGING THIS ASSERT THIS EXP***